Export styling from ArcGIS .lyrx to QGIS
I have an ArcGIS Pro Layer File (.lyrx) and I want to export it to QGIS. I managed to get the shapefiles, but I also want to export the styling (symbology) from this ArcGIS file to QGIS. Is it possible?

The conversion between ArcGIS style and QGIS Style is not natively supported, but there is a third party plugin that solves this problem: https://north-road.com/slyr/

Note that .lyrx conversion functionality is not available in the free "community" version of the SLYR plugin, you need the paid closed source licensed version

Yes, I have checked SLYR, but I can't pay for it. Is there any open source solution?

Try qlyrx. It's available as a QGIS plugin from the plugins menu (I've never used it so no idea if it works) https://github.com/arc2qgis/qlyrx
